# How to parse Soap XML in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a XML Like Below, But i am not able to parse it. Please help me to parse the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope     
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
<GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetResult>
<diffgr:diffgram>
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<a>hi1</a>
<b>hi2</b>
</Table>
<Table>
<a>hi3</a>
<b>hi4</b>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</GetResponse></GetResult>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here i want the results of the Table (i.e a,b ) tag. I tried using Linq but i am not able parse it. i tried the code some thing like this:

```
//XML will be there in response string
String response = e.response;
public static String myNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
XDocument reader = XDocument.Parse(response);
var results = from result in reader.Descendants(XName.Get("GetResponse", myNamespace))
              select result.Element("GetResult").
```

But this code is returning null.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: So why don't you just generate a client with the schema and let .Net do the parsing for you?

Comment: Thanks Bashwork. But I want to parse this XML in Windows Phone7.How can i parse this XML in WP7.

Comment: @MahiKumar - you can set a service reference in WP7 projects. Or do you mean that is should be dynamic because the schema will be different every time??

Comment: I added service reference and itried using that,but in Service they are returning dataset so dataset is not availbale wp7. So i have to use normal method of hitting URL and Get the XMl. So i have to parse the above XMl.

Answer (score 0):

In you c# project, you can import a Web Reference and make that point to the web service provider you are using. This reference will create an encapsulation class which will abstract all the SOAP protocol to you.

See the MSDN link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Carl T. I want to parse this XML in Windows Phone7.How can i parse this XML in WP7.

Comment: -1: why in the world would you post a .NET 1.1 link as an answer to a Windows Phone question? Also, why would you suggest the use of a Web Reference, which is legacy technology?

Comment: I added service reference and itried using that,but in Service they are returning dataset so dataset is not availbale wp7. So i have to use normal method of hitting URL and Get the XMl. So i have to parse the above XMl.

Comment: @JohnSaunders because when i answered it the header for windows phone 7 wasn`t there. Have a look at the edits for the post!

Comment: @CarlT.: that only makes it more mysterious. Do you really recommend .NET 1.1 and ASMX web services to people who are not using Windows Phone?